# How to insert data to php numeric array

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am trying to inset data to a numeric array [php graph](http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_pie1.php).

I tried to do it this way:

```
    $query = "select id,sales from riders";

    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        //$rider[i]=$row['id'];
         $rider[$counter]=$row['sales'];
        $counter++;
    }
```

and insert into data array as follows:

```
$data = array($rider[0],$rider[1],$rider[2],$rider[3],$rider[4]);
```

It gives me error.. Please help me... Thank you very much for your kind help.....

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Add `$counter = 0;` before the while loop.

PS: You can just use `$data[] = $row['sales'];` in the loop without the `$counter`.

Comment: if the key is not set, this wont cause an error, it will generate an empty key. Not good but not an error

Comment: @Talisin That will cause an notice, and the notice output will affect the graph out, maybe it is the error what OP means. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$rider[]`,

```
$rider=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
  $rider[]=$row['sales'];
}
```